# What would cause my site to have such a long wait time?

Tags: wordpress, loading

What would cause my wordpress site to have such a long wait time?

This only happens on the blog page and nothing is happening at all for 21 seconds.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1KLb.jpg

http://www.exactabacussoftware.com/blog

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: How many plugins you are using in your site ???

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools (F12 on Win) and look at the timeline. There's a 301 redirect in place that takes 19s, and then the page request takes another 22.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your server isn't responding quickly enough when sending out the data.
Which host are you using?

Check out GTMetrix's results for your site:

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.exactabacussoftware.com/QARO4k3X

Also check out their [WordPress Optimisation guide](http://gtmetrix.com/wordpress-optimization-guide.html).